# HNQ disappeared on /unanswered

Tags: bug, hot-questions

I normally browse SO via [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered). Since 2020-07-06 about 12:00 CEST the HNQ list disappeared. Before that everyting was fine, now the HNQ is missing. If I go to the [normal homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/) or look at a question everything is fine, i.e. HNQ is displayed.

Is this a bug or intentional? Or did I miss an anouncement?

Tested with Firefox, Chrome, Edge on Win 10, every browser shows the same behaviour. No error in the console.

Comment: [Yes, I can reproduce it - no HNQ](https://i.imgur.com/oQelnqJ.png)

Comment: Also, interesting to note that the custom filters are not shown on that page.

Comment: Related/cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345143/show-hot-network-questions-on-unanswered-questions-page. Also here on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered does show HNQ whereas https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered does not show it.

Comment: I blame Nick. He was testing something with caches.